# how to pass a function as a argument to another function in a controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

A very common question. help is really appreciated !!

i am not able to pass loginCtrl as a argument in SignupCtrl

Also if there is any proper way to do this please suggest

**here is the code**

```
     $scope.loginCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
            $scope.cancelLogin = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
        };

     $scope.signupCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance,loginCtrl){
$scope.close1=loginCtrl.cancelLogin;
            $scope.cancelLogin = function () {
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
        };
```

Comment: how do you use `signupCtrl`?

Comment: i am using it  in a function $scope.open to open a modal through a button
ng-click="open()"

Comment: a simple example to call a function as a argument in another function in a controller would be a great help. @dfsq

Comment: you are doing this totally incorrectly.  I started to write an answer explaining that using `$scope` means that the first `$scope.cancelLogin` is actually being overwritten by the second, but it actually doesn't matter, because what you are describing in comments to other posts doesn't make sense anyway.  You can't call one dialog from another, since you can only have one dialog active at a time in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind click event.

```
user.showModalDialog = function (item) {

    var obj = {
        selectedItem: item
    };
    _showModalDialog(obj);

};
```

**_showModalDialog Method**

```
var _showModalDialog = function (params) {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "your html template URL",
        backdrop: 'static',
        windowClass: 'modal-width-50',
        resolve: {
            params: function () { return params; }
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, params) {
           var user = params.selectedItem;
          // you can receive your params here in params.
          $scope.user=user;
   }
```

Another way of doing this,

```
var _showModalDialog = function (params) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "your html template URL",
            backdrop: 'static',
            controller: _userCtrl,
            windowClass: 'modal-width-50',
            resolve: {
                params: function () { return params; }
            }});
```

its controller in the same file, its the inline controller, you can also make it in external file.

```
var _userCtrl = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'params', function ($scope, $modalInstance, params) {
       var user = params.selectedItem;
       // you can receive your params here in params.
 $scope.user = user;
    }];
```

Second approach is, you can pass data between two controllers by use of service.

Comment: thanks  kashif bhai... i am able to open modal but i want to open a modal from a link in a another modal . for that i want to know how to pass a function as argument in another function so that i could close the first modal and open the other modal.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can also use second approach. For your particular scenario, in click event you close first dialog and open another. its quite simple. I hope you got your answer than please mark it as answer :) if you still face an issue please show it your working copy , i will help by looking at it. or you can it make jsfiddle .